# how to: convert the value of a string of char as a double back without atof

Tags: c, function, char, double, ascii

I got stucked with the function double ascii_to_float. My function should receives a string of char and give it the value as a double back. I´m not allowed to use atof().

I want to search for a the point in the string, to proof it if its a double. if not it should return -1.

```
double ascii_to_float(char *textzahl)
{
  int x;
  double ausgabe;

  sprintf(ausgabe,"%s",textzahl);

  /* here with -=48, i´m not sure how to code
 it right, i just now that i have to decrease with 48.*/

  for(x=0; x< strlen(textzahl); x++) 
  {
      if(textzahl[x]=='.')
      {
         textzahl[x]-=48; 
      }
      else
      {
          textzahl[x]=-1;
      }
  }
    
    return ausgabe;
}
```

The main function is given, so I have to just Write the code of above function.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
        char text[80];
        double zahl2;
    
        printf("\n bitte eine Zahl eingeben:"),
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
        zahl2= ascii_to_float ( text);
    
        if (zahl2==-1.0)
        {
            printf("\nfehlerhafte Eingabe oder Wert -1");
        }
        else
        {
           printf("\ndie Zahl2 lautet: %lf\n",zahl2);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: First of all please try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))). If, by the value `48` mean the ASCII code for `'0'` then better use `'0'` instead, as it's much clearer and also portable for other platforms which doesn't use ASCII.

Comment: Also please make it a habit to print *trailing* newlines. When `stdout` (to which `printf` writes) is connected to an actual terminal, then its *line buffered*, meaning output is actually written to the terminal on newline. So if you print a leading newline then you write the *previous* line, not the current line. Trailing newline will also make sure that the last output isn't mixed ti the terminal prompt.

Comment: And what is the *actual* text of your assignment? Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment text, including any and all requirements and limitations. There are a couple of other ways to convert a string to a `float` using the standard C functions, if the limitations mentions only `atof` then you could nitpick your way around one of those other functions.

Comment: [Start simple](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).  Do you know how to write code that works like `atoi()`?

Comment: Did the assignment tell you to return -1 if the string did not contain a decimal point?  If not, I wouldn't do it that way.  It's perfectly valid to convert the string `"123"` to the `double` value `123.0`. (Also, if you return -1 on error, how will you know whether it was an actual error, or the result of converting the string `"-1.0"`?)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow your terminologies means name of variables, functions... as it is time consuming for me.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

double fun(char*);

int main()
{
    char str1[]="2356.23", str2[]="234", str3[]="bonap.art" ,str4[]="33.42.2";
    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf", fun(str1),fun(str2),fun(str3),fun(str4));
}

double fun(char *s)
{
    int count=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(s)-1; i++)
    {

        if(s[i]=='.')
        {
            count++;
        }
        if(count==2)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if( !((s[i]>=48 && s[i]<=57)|| (s[i]=='.')) )
        {
            return -1;
        }

    }

    if(count==0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    double d;
    sscanf(s,"%lf",&d);
    return d;
}
```

**Output**

```
2356.230000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000
```

If you see code carefully you understand all. Still I explain some things.

you mentioned that to check given string is double or not you are checking `.` it contains point or not but that's not enough.

what if string contain 2 `.` (points) or characters like `a`, `b`, `*`,...   So To take care of these two problems I added `count`, `!((s[i]>=48 && s[i]<=57)|| (s[i]=='.'))` these conditions respectively. I will not elaborate if you not understand still, you can comment.

I don't understand why you choose `sprintf(ausgabe,"%s",textzahl);` rather than `sscanf(s,"%lf",&d);`

Also you can consider `strtod`  `float strtod (const char* str, char** endptr);` for your question. you can check out [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)